# how to remove implicit function and conflicting error declarations on a various functions calculator using C program?

Tags: c, function, calculator, void

I am somewhat done with making this function calculator on C program, but I have one issue, and it's really making me go nuts.
I can go through the code and everything, but I keep getting implicit declaration function and conflicting errors when I compile the code. 
How can I fix my code to get rid of them? 
I'm new to C, and programming in general. Thank you :)

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(){
 int response;

 do{

displayWelcomeMessage();

scanf("%d",&response);
selectOption(response);
 if(response<-1||response>8){
 printf("Please enter a number between 1 and 8\n");
 }

 }while(response!=-1);

 printf("Thanks for using the program!");
return 0;
}

void selectOption(int response){
 int adder(int x,int y);
 int subtract(int x,int y);
 int multiplicate(int x,int y);
 double divisor(int x,int y);
 int modeOperator(int x,int y);
 int factorialOperator(int x);
 double powerOperator(int x,int y);
 int FibonacciOperator(int x);
 int x,y;
switch(response){
case 1 :
 printf("the result is: %d\n",adder(x,y));
 break;

case 2 :
 printf("the result is: %d\n",subtract(x,y));
 break;

case 3 :
 printf("the result is: %d\n",multiplicate(x,y));
 break;

case 4 :
 printf("the result is: %lf\n",divisor(x,y));
 break;

case 5 :
 printf("the result is: %d\n",modeOperator(x,y));
 break;

case 6 :
 printf("Please enter a variable to calculate the factorial:\n");
 scanf("%d",&x);
 printf("the result is: %d\n",factorialOperator(x));
 break;

case 7 :
 printf("Enter base:\n");
 scanf("%d", &x);
 printf("Enter exponent:\n");
 scanf("%d", &y);
 printf("the result is: %lf\n",powerOperator(x,y));
 break;

case 8 :
 printf("enter a value:\n");
 scanf("%d",&x);
 for(int i=1;i<=x;i++){
 printf("%d\n",FibonacciOperator(i));
     }
 break;
}
}

void displayWelcomeMessage(){
printf("welcome to final programming homework!\n");
printf("please enter 1 for the addition operation\n");
printf("please enter 2 for the subtraction operation\n");
printf("please enter 3 for the multiplication operation\n");
printf("please enter 4 for the division operation\n");
printf("please enter 5 for the mode operation\n");
printf("please enter 6 for the factorial operation\n");
printf("please enter 7 for the power operation\n");
printf("please enter 8 for the Fibonacci operation\n");
printf("please enter -1 to exit\n");
}

int adder(int x,int y){
 printf("please enter two variables to be added:\n");
 scanf("%d %d",&x,&y);
 return x+y;
}

int subtract(int x,int y){
 printf("please enter two variables to be subtracted:\n");
 scanf("%d %d",&x,&y);
 return x-y;
}

int multiplicate(int x,int y){
 printf("please add two variables to be multiplied:\n");
 scanf("%d %d",&x,&y);
 return x*y;
}

double divisor(int x,int y){
 printf("please add two variables to be divided:\n");
 scanf("%d %d",&x,&y);
 return (double)x/(double)y;
}

int modeOperator(int x,int y){
 printf("please add two variables to find the reminder:\n");
 scanf("%d %d",&x,&y);
 return x%y;
}

int factorialOperator(int x){
 if (x==1)
 return 1;
 else
 return x*factorialOperator(x-1);
}

double powerOperator(int x,int y){
 if(y == 0)
 return 1;
 else if(y > 0)
 return (double)x * powerOperator(x,y-1);
 else
 return 1 / powerOperator(x,-y);
}

int FibonacciOperator(int x){
 if (x==1 || x==2)
 return 1;
 else
 return FibonacciOperator(x-1)+FibonacciOperator(x-2);
}
```

Comment: Please don't deface your post.  It invalidates existing answers and doesn't make for a complete question.

Answer (score 2):

You're calling functions before they are defined or declared.

The C compiler runs in a single pass, so if you call a function before it's declared you'll get a warning.   In that case the compiler will assume the function returns `int`.  When the compiler then finds the actual definition, if it doesn't match the implicit definition you'll get an error.

You can fix this by either rearranging the functions so that they're defined before they're used, or by adding declarations for those functions at the top of the file.

So instead of:

```
int main(){
    ...
    displayWelcomeMessage();
    ...
}

void displayWelcomeMessage(){
    ...
}
```

You want:

```
void displayWelcomeMessage(){
    ...
}

int main(){
    ...
    displayWelcomeMessage();
    ...
}
```

Or:

```
void displayWelcomeMessage();

int main(){
    ...
    displayWelcomeMessage();
    ...
}

void displayWelcomeMessage(){
    ...
}
```

Do the same for all functions other than `main`.

Comment: It is also recommended to use `(void)` if the function takes no arguments  , empty parentheses are deprecated

Comment: @liliannn Look closely at what I wrote.  The function declarations go at the top before `main`, and they should look just like the definition except that they end in a `;` and don't have a body.

Comment: As @dbush said, declare functions before you use them. C is a structured language so it executes its instructions in sequential manner until a branch is found. One more thing, I'd really suggest you to read about **function prototypes** in C.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the header file for the functions that you use before defining. Either because they come from the standard library such as scanf or because you define them later.